# The matplotlib cannot work after the update of VSCode. This application failed to start because it could not find or load Qt platform plugin "windows"

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter([1,1],[2,2])
plt.show()
```

Error:

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the
> Qt platform plugin "windows" in
> "D:\Anaconda\envs...\Lib\site-packages\qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0\Library\plugins\platforms".
>
> Available platform plugins are: direct2d, minimal, offscreen, windows.
>
> Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Such error first occurred after the update of VSCode, and then disappeared after another update. Recently, it occurred again after the version 1.68.1 of VSCode.

Comment: What version of windows do you have? I'm guessing it's not 10.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code in versions 1.68.0 and 1.68.1 respectively, and I didn't encounter this problem. I don't think this is the problem with vscode.

[image]

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""

This is caused by a path error. Try reinstalling the CONDA environment.